# MS Remote Desktop on MacBook running Yosemite

Tags: macos, remote-desktop

I am running Yosemite 10.10.5 on my 13" MacBook (Early 2014) and I want to make remote connections to a Windows PC. When I go to the App Sotre and try to install the Microsoft Remote Desktop app I get this messgae:

"Microsoft Remote Desktop can't be installed because OS X version 10.13 or later is required".

Since I am stuck with Yosemite how can I obtain an older version of the Remote Desktop app. Presumably it worked previously when Yosemite was the latest version?

Comment: You are not stuck with Yosemite. IIRC all Macs 2012 or 2013 and newer are able to run macOS Catalina, on which RDP from the App Store will work great. You should definitely upgrade for many reasons, the most important of them is security.

Answer (score 2):

There is no Macbook "Early 2014". There's a Macbook Air Early 2014, which is perfectly capable of running Catalina 10.15 & is not 'stuck' with Yosemite.

Microsoft have removed RDC v8 from the app store so your best chance  if their support won’t help you is from a 3rd party site - google "microsoft remote desktop 8 mac" for a few sources… however, whether or not these can be trusted is another thing entirely.

As your OS is so far out of date that it's already insecure, I wouldn't be rushing to download other potentially insecure things to it.

Comment: I agree - if OP won’t upgrade the OS (and there always is a trade off / reasons to delay) another tool is likely the best if some internet archivist hasn’t squirreled away old downloads and release notes. RDC isn’t listed as an office component. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ but Kaizala sure made the cut (lol)

Comment: Thanks for the replies - if I can install Catalina then great. I went to App Store -> updates - it says "no updates available".

Comment: Ok I got there eventually. I had just assumed that my MacBook was not able to run Catalina since I had received no prompts to install it. So I cam e here to ask about a question and walk away with the the latest OS for my machine. Awesome thanks!